# Variables in XSLT how to declare , assign value and use that variable in a different location in the same XSLT

Tags: variables, xslt

Please consider my "A/B" xPath expression returns the following node

```
  <Q ID="12345">
  ----
  ----
  </Q>
```

This is my variable

This is how I’m trying to assign a value to my tempVariable variable

```
  <xsl:for-each select="A/B">
  <xsl:variable name="tempVariable"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:variable>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

And after all I’m trying to use this variable

```
  <xsl:if test="$tempVariable='12345'">
  ....
  ....
  </xsl:if>
```

but here as I understand I’m getting $tempVariable ="" which is not correct.

Can someone please tell me where I’m doing wrong or how can I do this in proper way.
Thank you.

Comment: So Q is a child of B? ... then it should be Q/@ID ...

Comment: Seee the answer to similar quetion posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066455/declare-global-variable-in-xslt-re-assign-a-value-locally/25338485#25338485

Answer (score 8):

Why would a path like `A/B` select a `Q` element? If you want to use a variable you need to make sure it is in scope. The variable you show in your sample is in scope inside the `xsl:for-each`, after the `xsl:variable` element.

If you want to use the variable outside the `for-each` you would need to declare it outside the `for-each`.

However I think you can simply do

```
<xsl:variable name="v1" select="A/B/@ID"/>
<xsl:if test="$v1 = '12345'">..</xsl:if>
```

there is no need for the `for-each`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Martin. How can I reassign a value to variable "v1" there, seems like XSLT does not permit me to reassign a values to a variable ??

Comment: XSLT is a declarative programming language while assignment and in particular reassignment to variables is a concept of procedural programming assuming some sequential execution order of statements. That is not how XSLT works and if you need help solving a problem in XSLT and are not yet familiar with it then consider to post an input sample and the corresponding result sample you want to create, then people here can show you an XSLT way of solving the problem.